# Change charset in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encoding, character-encoding, laravel-5

Is there a way to change the default charset (UTF-8) to ISO-8859-1 in Laravel Framework?

I already tried:

Adding headers to routes;

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
Route::get('/notificacao/nova','NotificacaoController@nova', $headers);
```

Comment: The character set applies to: Database client, database server, file content, file names, request stream, response stream. You have to be a bit more specific on what you want to change.

Comment: Can you verify that your browser receives the header correctly? E.g. open de Chrome developer console, open the Network tab, click on the `/notificacao/nova` request, and verify the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Specifying the charset on headers only influences how the browser will read the content. If your data is in UTF-8 on database, or at your code, you will need to convert it to ISO too.

Answer (score 3):

I had your same problem and solved it adding a middleware which replaces UTF-8 with ISO-8859-1 in the Content-Type *charset* header.

I created a new middleware class, named `CharsetMiddleware`, with these contents:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CharsetMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $contentType = $response->headers->get('Content-Type');
        if (!empty($contentType)) {
            $response->header('Content-Type', str_replace('UTF-8', 'iso-8859-1', $contentType));
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

I put it in *app/Http/Middleware/* folder, and then in *app/Http/Kernel.php* class added the class reference at the end of `$middleware` array property, like this:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ... Other middleware references
    \App\Http\Middleware\CharsetMiddleware::class,
];
```